# Manually adding columns to rallycardboard component

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am creating a `rallycardboard` where each column represents a release, and the cards are Features to be scheduled into those releases. The default mechanics of the component render all available releases as columns on the board. For our particular application this is unreasonable, since there are thousands of Releases in our workspace.

I was able to overwrite the `addColumn` method to only include a column if it is a Release which at least one Feature from the group is assigned to. The next step is to make it so that a user can manually add a Release column that doesn't currently have any assigned work. To do this, I stored all the excluded columns from the first step and created a combo box with those values. I would like it so that when the user selects a Release from the combo box, that Release column is added to the board.

I was able to reconfigure my `addColumn` method to allow for manual override (as apposed to trying to match with an existing Feature's Release). I verified that the column was added to the boards columns by calling `board.getColumns()` and the configurations look the same for both the existing and added columns. However, I get an error message when calling `board.renderColumns()` which appears to be the result of trying to write to a container that doesn't yet exist (the column isn't created yet).

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Is there another way I can more easily decide which columns to include, and which to exclude, on the `rallycardboard` component?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where the board columns are based on releases that have features scheduled. To add a columns for releases that have no features currently scheduled select releases from the mulitpicker.

The app is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/feature-board-by-rel).

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    _releasesWithFeatures: [],
    _uniqueColumns: [],
    _additionalColumns: [],
    _updatedColumns: [],
    _cardBoard: null,

    launch: function() {
        var that = this;
        this._releasePicker = Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose a Release',
            modelType: 'Release'
        });
        this.add(this._releasePicker);

        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallybutton',
            id: 'getReleases',
            text: 'Add Selected Releases',
            handler: function(){
                that._getSelectedReleases();
            }
        })

        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
            fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','Release'],
            pageSize: 100,
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: [
                {
                    property: 'Release',
                    operator: '!=',
                    value: null
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                load: this._onScheduledFeaturesLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        }); 
    },
    _onScheduledFeaturesLoaded: function(store, data){
        var that = this;
        if (data.length !==0) {
            _.each(data, function(feature){
                console.log('feature ', feature.get('FormattedID'), 'scheduled for ', feature.get('Release')._refObjectName, feature.get('Release')._ref);
                that._releasesWithFeatures.push(feature.get('Release'))
            });
            that._makeBoard();
        }
        else{
            console.log('there are no features scheduled for a release')
        }
    },
    _makeBoard: function(){
       if (this._cardBoard) {
            this._cardBoard.destroy();
        }

        var columns = [];

        _.each(this._releasesWithFeatures, function(rel){
            columns.push({value: rel._ref, columnHeaderConfig: {headerTpl: '{release}', headerData: {release: rel._refObjectName}}});
        });

        this._uniqueColumns = _.uniq(columns, 'value');

            var cardBoard = {
                xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                itemId: 'piboard',
                types: ['PortfolioItem/Feature'],
                attribute: 'Release',
                fieldToDisplay: 'Release',
                columns: this._uniqueColumns           
            };

            this._cardBoard = this.add(cardBoard);
    },

    _getSelectedReleases: function(){
        var that = this;
        var expandedColumns = [];
        var selectedReleases = this._releasePicker._getRecordValue();
        console.log(selectedReleases.length);
        if (selectedReleases.length > 0) {
            _.each(selectedReleases, function(rel) {
                var releaseName = rel.get('Name');
                var releaseRef = rel.get('_ref');
                that._additionalColumns.push({value: releaseRef, columnHeaderConfig: {headerTpl: '{release}', headerData: {release: releaseName}}});
            });
        }
        expandedColumns =  _.union(that._uniqueColumns, that._additionalColumns);
        this._updatedColumns = _.uniq(expandedColumns, 'value');
        this._updateBoard();


    },

    _updateBoard: function(){
        var that = this;

        if (this._cardBoard) {
            this._cardBoard.destroy();
        }
        var cardBoard = {
            xtype: 'rallycardboard',
            types: ['PortfolioItem/Feature'],
            attribute: 'Release',
            fieldToDisplay: 'Release',
            columns: that._updatedColumns,            
        };

        this._cardBoard = this.add(cardBoard);

    }

});
```